# Compare object instances of different classes for equality by their attributes

Tags: python, class

I have two classes:

```
class A:                    
def __init__(self, name, id=None, created_at=None):
    self.name = name
    self.id = id
    self.created_at = created_at
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.id} {self.name} {self.created_at}"
def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.id} {self.name} {self.created_at}"
def __eq__(self, other):
    if (isinstance(other, A)):
        return self.id == other.a_id
```

And

```
    class B:                    
def __init__(self, id, a_id, created_at=None):
    self.id = id
    self.a_id = a_id
    self.created_at = created_at
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.id} {self.name} {self.created_at}"
def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.id} {self.name} {self.created_at}"
def __eq__(self, other):
    if (isinstance(other, B)):
        return self.a_id == other.id
```

My goal is to get a == b is true if a.id == b.a_id .
Like comparing a primary key of a with a foreign key of b.
I know **eq** is not working because I want to compare two different classes.
Is there a way to do this in python 3?

Comment: ... Don't use `isinstance(other, B)` etc? But you are going to have to handle the case where `other.id` doesn't exist.